# Bayes Estimator under $L_{\eta}$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian

I am wondering if the following loss function is well known and if it is, does it have a standard name:

$$
L_{\eta} (\theta, a) = (\theta-a) (\eta - \mathbb{I}_{(-\infty, a)} (\theta) ), \quad \eta \in (0,1).
$$
where $\eta$ is fixed.

For the following problem:
For a single observation $x \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$, with prior on $\theta$ being $\tau(\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta} \mathbb{I}_{(0, \infty)}(\theta)$, we get the following posterior distribution:
\begin{align*}
    h_{\Theta|X}(\theta|x) = e^{x-\theta} \mathbb{I}_{(x, \infty)}(\theta).
\end{align*}
I am trying to compute the bayes estimator, $\hat{\theta}$, under $L_{\eta}$. I am wondering if my answer is correct, here is my working:

We wish to find $\hat{\theta}$ that minimises the expected posterior loss:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[L_{\theta}(\theta, \hat{\theta}) | X] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\theta - \hat{\theta}) (\eta - \mathbb{I}_{(-\infty, \hat{\theta})}(\theta)) h(\theta|x) d \theta \\
    &=(\eta -1)\int_{-\infty}^{\hat{\theta}} (\theta - \hat{\theta})  h(\theta|x) d \theta  + \eta \int_{\hat{\theta}}^{\infty} (\theta - \hat{\theta})  h(\theta|x) d \theta.
\end{align*}

Using Leibniz rule to differentiate this wrt $\hat{\theta}$ and setting to zero (and omitting some minor details), we get

\begin{align*}
    - (\eta -1) \int_{-\infty}^{\hat{\theta}} h(\theta|x) d \theta  - \eta \int_{\hat{\theta}}^{\infty}  h(\theta|x) d \theta = 0.
\end{align*}

Solving for $\hat{\theta}$ gives

\begin{align*}
    & -(\eta -1)\int_{-\infty}^{\hat{\theta}}  e^{x-\theta} \mathbb{I}_{(x, \infty)}(\theta) d \theta  - \eta \int_{\hat{\theta}}^{\infty}  e^{x-\theta} \mathbb{I}_{(x, \infty)}(\theta) d \theta = 0\\
    \implies & -(\eta -1) e^{x} \int_{\min \{ \hat{\theta}, x \} }^{\hat{\theta}} e^{-\theta} d \theta  - \eta e^{x} \int_{\max\{\hat{\theta}, x\}}^{\infty}  e^{-\theta}  d \theta = 0\\
    \implies & -(\eta -1) e^{x} \int_{ x }^{\hat{\theta}} e^{-\theta} d \theta  - \eta e^{x} \int_{\hat{\theta}}^{\infty}  e^{-\theta} d \theta = 0\\
    \implies & -(\eta -1) (1-e^{x- \hat{\theta}}) - \eta e^{x - \hat{\theta}} = 0\\
    \implies & \hat{\theta}= x-\log(1-\eta).
\end{align*}

Note that we have made the assumption that $\hat{\theta} \ge x$, so that
\begin{align*}
    \min \{\hat{\theta}, x \} = x, \quad \max \{\hat{\theta}, x \} = \hat{\theta},
\end{align*}